# Apache httpd issues after installing Yosemite (OS X)

Tags: apache, osx-yosemite

I just installed OS X Yosemite and am already regretting it.
My fully configured apache server won't run anymore and I am getting this error (when I do apachectl -S):

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 59 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so into server: dlopen(/usr/libexec/apache2/mod_authn_default.so, 10): image not found
```

Can someone help me fixing these kind of issues?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

PHP seems to be the culprit.  I re-installed PHP and that fixed the issue for me.  I used the 1-line package install from http://php-osx.liip.ch/  They just released a version compatible with Yosemite.

If you're wary about some random dude posting a .ch website, I don't blame you.  Check out the package details on the PHP website here which will give more info: http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.php

I hope that helps.